# ADO.net Entity Model Framework Compiled Query issue

Tags: .net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have the following code through which I am trying to create a CompiledQuery using LINQ.

```
public static Func<DataContext, int, object>
        GetTeamMembersByTeamId = CompiledQuery.Compile<MazikReviewEntities, int, object>(
            (context, teamId) => from tp in context.TeamPlayers
                                    join t in context.Teams on tp.TeamId equals t.ID
                                    join emp in context.Employees on tp.EmployeeId equals emp.ID
                                    where tp.TeamId == teamId && emp.IsActive == true
                                    orderby emp.JoiningDate
                                    select new ProjTeamMemberDetails
                                    {
                                        EmployeeName = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName,
                                        Email = emp.Email,
                                        Designation = context.Designations.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == emp.DesignationId).Name,
                                        NIC = emp.NIC,
                                        JoiningDate = emp.JoiningDate,
                                        EmployeeID = emp.ID
               });

}
```

In the line CompiledQuery.Compile I am getting an error for my datacontext which states that,

> "The type 'MazikGlobalReviewModel.MazikReviewEntities' cannot be used as type parameter 'TArg0' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Compile(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MazikGlobalReviewModel.MazikReviewEntities' to 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext'."

What is this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My friend from Mazik. If you look at the error its very clear what is wrong there.
Take a look at the following code. What is datacontext and MazikReviewEntities in your code .Make sure they are of same type.

```
 public static readonly Func<**MyDataContext**, int, IQueryable<tblSomething>> CompiledSelectSites =
                CompiledQuery.Compile((**MyDataContext** c, int conf_id) =>
                        (from s in c.TblSomething
                         where s.ID == id
                         select site));
```

For more look at this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/05/05/linq-to-sql-understanding-compiled-query.aspx).

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: changes my code, but still getting the same error'public static readonly Func<MazikReviewEntities, int, IQueryable<ProjTeamMemberDetails>>
            GetTeamMembersByTeamId = CompiledQuery.Compile((MazikReviewEntities context, int teamId, IQueryable<ProjTeamMemberDetails> obj)
                 =>'

Comment: The call to Compile should only include your input parameters not your output. Please look at the code that i mentioned and secondly go through the link that is included in the answer. Remove your IQueryable<ProjTeamMemberDetails>  from CompiledQuery.Compile call.

Comment: done exactly the same mentioned in the link. Also updated my code according to your code. But no luck. I think there is some issue with my DataContext which is MazikReviewEntities

Comment: I think in Link2SQL we have datacontext created from db. while in ADO.net entity framework we don't have datacontext

Comment: I dont know what you mean to say here , In either cases you create files from database to work on . dbml in case of Linq and edmx in case of EF.